# A privilege that the service requires to start doesn't exist in the Service Account

Tags: powershell, cmd.exe, windows-server, windows-services

Using CarbonDLLs and sc config I am able to grant the user `Logon As Service` rights and also able to add the user as the Services' Log on as account.

Previously I was getting `Logon Failure` but after using carbon and powershell script I was able to remove that error by granting `Logon as Service` permission to the account.

But now when I start the service I get the following error:

```
A privilege that the service requires to start does not exist in the Service Account....
```

For Service Account I'm using a user account from AD which is also added as a Local Administrator on the server on which I am changing the services' log on as account.

For testing I was changing the Logon As Account of `Themes` service which by default runs under the Local System Account. I don't want to run it under Local System but under the Account Ive assigned

Comment: [powershell - How to view user privileges using windows cmd? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11607389/how-to-view-user-privileges-using-windows-cmd) run on both accounts to see what privileges you are missing.

Comment: How do I find privileges of a Local System Account. This link doesn't mention that

Comment: Ok I've found the privileges that a Local System Account has from this official link
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/localsystem-account. So I'll have to map these all to the Account I created?

Comment: [LocalSystem Account - Win32 apps | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/localsystem-account)

Comment: But the user is in the Local Administrator Group. It must have SERVICES_ALL_ACCESS

Comment: That's an access thing. [AccessChk - Windows Sysinternals | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/accesschk)

Comment: Does the error message mention which privilege is missing? If not, you may find more info in the Event Viewer. Is the service granted interactive access? Is the account in this case a domain account?

Comment: No it doesn't show any info. It's a domain account and in the local administrators group of the computer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Members of the local group `Administrators` have many privileges, but definitely not all. One of those extra privileges is the one you already set: `Logon as a service`. You can find and manage all privileges in the Local Security Settings MMC snap-in (secpol.msc) under *Security Settings > Local Policies > User Rights Assignment*:

[image]

As you can see, not all (allowing) rights contain the `Administrators` group. If everything worked well, you will already see your domain user under `Logon as a service`. If not, add it now. This is the minimum requirement for a user account to run an executable<sup>1</sup> as a service.

Running the `Themes` service of course also needs the `Logon as a service` right. But as you observed - for this service - it is not enough. This particular service also needs the `Replace a process level token` right. Btw., to learn more about a particular right, just open it and navigate to the *Explain* tab:

[image]

So, in conclusion, to run the `Themes` service under your domain user, add this account to the `Logon as a service` and `Replace a process level token` policies.

A recommendation: Please do not add a user to every allowing policy, to "make things work". This may impose serious security flaws.

## How can I find out which privileges a particular service needs?

As Windows services have to implement the [Windows services API](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsvc/), they will contain a [SERVICE_REQUIRED_PRIVILEGES_INFOA](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsvc/ns-winsvc-service_required_privileges_infoa) structure. This contains a list of all required privileges. You can use [this C++ code](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/querying-a-service-s-configuration) to query this info. Alternatively, you can download the [SystemExtensions module](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/SystemExtensions/) for PowerShell and use the `Get-ServiceConfig` cmdlet:

```
Get-ServiceConfig Themes | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Privileges
```

Output:

```
SeAssignPrimaryTokenPrivilege
SeDebugPrivilege
SeImpersonatePrivilege
```

You can then use [this documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/authorization-constants) to translate these privileges into the policy names (same order as above):

- Replace a process level token
- Debug programs
- Impersonate a client after authentication

---

<sup>1</sup> Keep in mind that not all executables can be run as a service, as they have to implement the [Windows services API](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsvc/) at least.

Comment: Secondly by default `Themes` service runs under local system account and it's not added in `Replace process level token` but it's still able to run `Themes` service. So what's the catch there? Thanks

Comment: "I cannot find where you found out that Themes service requires..." Read the last paragraph I added. "local system account and it's not added..." `Local System` is equivalent to the account `SYSTEM` with SID `S-1-5-18`. It is the system itself, it has all privileges.